# Sorting an array of pointers using bubble sort, returns unsorted array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, struct

I got stuck with sorting an array of pointers, and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Basically, I have to read files, and create two arrays, one is an array of structures, and the other is an array of pointers to those structures. And then I have to sort both arrays, first pointer one, and then structures one, and time how long it will take (for now I don't care about time). 
After I run the program, looks like bubble_sort_ptr() do not sort the array. So, I think either I wrote a bad function, and when I am creating an array of pointers, I am doing something wrong there.

```
    
    #include 
    #include 

    #define MAX_SIZE 500 /* max size of the file in kB */
    #define NUM_OF_FILES 10 /* number of file to read, and sort */



    typedef struct file_txt     /* structure to store file information */
    {
    char filename[10];
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE * 8 * 1000]; /* Null terminated text from the file */
    int size;   /* size of the file */
    } file_txt;



    void bubble_sort(file_txt array[]);
    void bubble_sort_ptr(file_txt **arr);



    int main()
    {
        int i;
    file_txt* files;    /* an array to store file information */
    file_txt* files_ptr[NUM_OF_FILES];  /* an array to store pointers to file information */
    if((files = (file_txt*) malloc(sizeof(file_txt) * NUM_OF_FILES)) == NULL) /* allocate memory for files array */
    {
        printf("Error calling malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i  arr[k+1].size) /* decreasing order */
                        {
                                temp = arr[k];
                                arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                                arr[k+1] = temp;
                        }
                }
        }
    }


    void bubble_sort_ptr(file_txt **arr)
    {
        int i, j;
        file_txt *temp;
        //printf("Inside ptr sort\n");
        for(i = 0; i  (*arr)[j+1].size)
                {
                    temp = *(arr+j);
                    *(arr+j) = *(arr+j+1);
                    *(arr+j+1) = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate, if somebody could explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: ***[Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)***

Comment: Wrong in your code? or wrong by *not* posting it *here* ??

Comment: Do you know the difference between `(*arr)[j].size` and `arr[j]->size` ? If you think they're synonymous, you're mistaken. The latter dereferences the j'th pointer in the pointer array. Your code dereferences the j'th *structure* based from the *first* pointer in the pointer array.

Comment: If you were to remove or modify the file to which you have linked it would no longer be relevant to the question posted, so please post the code you need help with.

Comment: @WhozCraig Does is it make difference if I just need to compare sizes of structures that they are pointing to?

Comment: @winterblood sorry, I added the code.

Comment: Did you understand what i commented? If so, you likely wouldn't have asked. If not, the followup question really isn't relevant until you do.

Comment: Sorry, at first I didn't understood what you meant, I am relatively new to C.
I changed in the code as you suggested and it works now.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is your main problem:

```
for(i = 0; i  arr[k+1].size)
```

You are missing a "<" sign and an "i++" in both of your for loops.